# Is it possible to call the header value as a parameter for the method applied to the same object in simple interpreter, Spring DSL for Apache Camel?

Tags: java, apache-camel, camel-spring-dsl

Is it possible to call something like this in Apache Camel's Spring DSL

```
 <setHeader headerName="timestampPart3"><simple>${header.timestampPart2.substring(0, ${header.timestampPart2.length()} - 2)}</simple></setHeader>
```

or like this

```
 <setHeader headerName="timestampPart3"><simple>${header.timestampPart2.substring(0, header.timestampPart2.length() - 2)}</simple></setHeader>
```

For the second attempt it identifies `.length() - 2` as a single method name call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increment and decrement with simple, so...

I wouldn't recommend, but for example:

```
<setHeader headerName="timestampPart2_1">
    <simple>${header.timestampPart2.length()}--</simple>
</setHeader>

<setHeader headerName="timestampPart2_1">
    <simple>${header.timestampPart2_1}--</simple>
</setHeader>

<setHeader headerName="timestampPart3">
    <simple>${header.timestampPart2.substring(0, ${header.timestampPart2_1})}</simple>
</setHeader>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to use `groovy` instead of `simple` for doing that.

```
<setHeader headerName="timestampPart3"><groovy>
     request.headers.get('timestampPart2').split("\\.")[0]
     </groovy></setHeader>
```